# How to retrieve the id attribute value in MagicSuggest?

Tags: jquery, html, magicsuggest

I am using a couple of [MagicSuggest](http://nicolasbize.github.io/magicsuggest) controls on my page, with the following code:

```
<div id="my_id1" class="magicsuggest"></div>
<div id="my_id2" class="magicsuggest"></div>

...

var ms = $('.magicsuggest').magicSuggest({});
$(ms).on('selectionchange', function(event, combo, selection){
    var id = combo.input[0].offsetParent.id;

    ...
});
```

I have found this quite cumbersome way to retrieve back the `id` of my `<div>`, but am wondering if there is more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not trying to get the ID of the combobox but of its container.

How about this:

```
    var ms = $('.magicsuggest').magicSuggest({});
    $(ms).on('selectionchange', function(event, combo, selection){
        var id = combo.container[0].id;

        ...
    });
```